Passing parameters between notebooks that belong to different Databricks workflows
Scenario (in Databricks):

TaskA is a task of type 'Notebook' in Job1 workflow. TaskA utilizes NotebookA.
Job1 is a first task of type 'Run_Job' in Job2 workflow.
TaskB is a second task of type 'Notebook' in Job2. TaskB utilizes NotebookB.
NotebookB takes an input parameter.
NotebookB depends on Job1.

Objective: While running Job2, pass a parameter set in NotebookA (nested inside Job1) into NotebookB.
Passing parameter works if both NotebookA and NotebookB belong to a single workflow.
NotebookA sets a task value dbutils.jobs.taskValues.set("key1","value1"), and then NotebookB retrieves it referencing {{tasks.TaskA.values.key1}}.
However, if NotebookA is within Job1 task (the desired scenario), then NotebookB does not see the parameter. The attempt to reference this {{tasks.Job1.values.key1}} fails. The exception thrown: Failed to resolve references: Task value referenced by 'tasks.Job1.values.key1' was not found.
NotebookB should retrieve key1 parameter set in NotebookA
